# Xamarin.Android can't create Facebook login button

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin, xamarin.android

As I searched for the answer to my question I saw some solutions which didn't helped me.. So the problem is that in my xamarin android app I'm trying to create facebook authentication, so first move is to create facebook login button

**FacebookLoginView.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It looks like this 
[image]

**FacebookLoginView.cs**

```
 [Activity(Label = "Facebook login")]
 class FacebookLoginView : MvxActivity
 {
    private LoginButton loginButton;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        //FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize(ApplicationContext);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.FacebookLoginView);    
    }
}
```

When I run the code I'm getting this exception:

[image]

When I uncomment `FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize(ApplicationContext);` and run the app I'm getting this error:

[image]

So there are no info about the second error and I don't know how can I fix this... Could someone please explain me what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**
I managed to update Xamarin.Facebook.Android from 4.16.1 to the latest version 4.24.0, but the errors are the same....

Comment: FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize has be deprecated since 3.x, what version of the Facebook SDK are you using as normally the Facebook `LoginButton` should exist in in a fragment and you register the callbacks against the button and those callbacks provide the login results and the access token if successful.

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm using Xamarin.Facebook.Android 4.16.1 and can't install the latest 4.24.0 version because I'm getting this error : "Could not install package 'Xamarin.Facebook.Android 4.22.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

Comment: @SushiHangover I updated my question